# Android: Debug native memory allocation without root?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, heap-memory

I'd like to do some C++ memory management validation on my Android app.

I know about https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-memory.html, but I'm wondering if there's any way to do this sort of thing without a rooted device or using the emulator.

It feels like there should be a way to simply build a special development version of the app that forces memory debugging -- without having to root the whole device.  But I don't see any such options.

Comment: You can try address sanitizer https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan.html or valgrind

Comment: @AlexCohn any good quick HOWTO for either of them? All the ones I found require root and/or feel obsolete or very hacky...